# How do I find android method constants (or, how to use android.com)

Tags: android

I've had trouble using developer.android.com as a reference. Is it incomplete, or do I just need some advice on how to use it, or is there a better reference?

for example:  for the "TextView.BufferType" method, I can't find out on developer.android.com what are the possible variables. I know of "EDITABLE", but what are the others? The android.com reference to TextViewBufferType gives no clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EDITABLE`, `NORMAL`, and `SPANNABLE`. They seemed to have nuked the "Enum Values" section in all HTML documentation in the 3.0 release. They still exist in Google's cached copy, though (as of 2/25/2011): http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.BufferType.html

You can also still see the available values in Eclipse's autocomplete, and obviously they're there if you check out the actual AOSP source code (highly recommended). Why they removed useful web documentation on enums is beyond me, though.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `BufferType` is not a method, it's an enum.

You'll also see on top that there is an XML attribute called buffer type, and it is listed to have three states [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3abufferType): normal, spannable, editable, and you have those equivalents in the BufferType enum (in all upper-case, of course).

Comment: Those are the XML values (useful) but the actual Java enum value documentation that existed in 2.3.3 seems to have been removed for all enums in the 3.0 docs. Strange.

Comment: I can't find any reference to XML attributes or any of mention of states, et.. that you mention. Perhaps I'm in the wrong section called "Reference" in developer.android.com, but this is the section that Google always takes me to. Also there are no links in this page. Can you copy me on the link you're using?

Comment: Your link (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3abufferType) goes to the documentation on the XML attribute `android:bufferType` in the TextView's "XML Attributes" section. In this particular case, the possible values for that XML field correspond closely to the names of enum values from TextView.BufferType that you'd use in equivalent Java code, but that isn't always the case and there are some enums in Android that don't have matching XML attributes (some are for properties not settable via XML, and many enums don't have to do with Views).